# How to pass Parameters from Web-pack to Code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, gulp

I have a gulp task which takes in the parameter **location** using yargs. And i use webpack to give the entry point to my application

```
 webpackConfig.entry.push('BootStrapper.ts');
```

I have a webpack config which has entrypoint to bootstrapper.

```
module.exports = {
entry: [],
output: {
    path: require("path").resolve('./dist/'),
    filename: 'MyProcess.built.js'
 },
}
```

I want to pass a variable the **location** variable to Bootstrapper.ts is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is.

First, adjust your *webpack config* to receive parameters:

```
{
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.YOUR_UNIQUE_VARIABLE': JSON.stringify(process.env.YOUR_UNIQUE_VARIABLE)
    )
  ]
}
```

then, in your *Bootstrapper.ts* you can write something like this:

```
const buildVariable = process.env.YOUR_UNIQUE_VARIABLE;
```

If you now run your webpack script (I assume to run a npm script) passing the variable like:

```
cross-env YOUR_UNIQUE_VARIABLE=value webpack
```

your code will be compiled to:

```
const buildVariable = 'value';
```